# Reading the second (or subsequent) line in Korn Shell

Tags: ksh

My OS is AIX (7200-05-03-2136) and my Korn Shell version is ksh88 (Version M-11/16/88f), but I think my question doesn't depend on versions.

Consider a single-line output of a command. I can easily put this into a variable via "read":

`command | read variable`

Now, suppose the command would have a two-line output. Is there a way to capture only the second line into a variable? It would be easy to use some external program like, i.e.:

`command | sed '1d' | read variable`

But I would like to avoid that and find a pure shell-solution. I have tried the following variations:

```
    command | { read -r junk ; read -r variable }
    command | { IFS=\n read junk ; read variable }
    command | IFS='\n' read junk variable
```

But all these won't work.

Comment: command | tail -1 amounts to the same as command | sed '1d'. The point of my question is actually if this can be done within shell, not with external commands.

Comment: Define "won't work". What does happen, and how does that differ from your expectation?

Comment: It is `command | { read -r variable; read -r variable; }`

Comment: assuming the requirement could change (eg, 2nd line this time, 1st line next time, etc), use a `while read -r x; do ...; done < <(command)` loop and a counter; when the counter hits the desired line number you store the value in `variable` and `break` out of the loop

Comment: "won't work" obviously means that the variable won't get filled with the content i would like it to be filled, in this case the second line of the output of "command". I thought that would be obvious from the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assign everything to a variable first. Next you can print or assign the second line.

```
variable=$(echo "line 1
line 2")
echo "${variable#*$'\n'}"
# or
variable="${variable#*$'\n'}"
```